# SQL query seems to have an Error

Tags: sql, codeigniter, foxpro, dbf

I have a DBF - foxpro query and seems like I have an error, I am using codeIgniter and its feedback is just **Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\accounting\system\database\drivers\pdo\pdo_driver.php on line 193** and I have encountered this error many times already and it means I have an error in my SQL but I cant figure out where. here are my tables

#### GUESTS

#### Guest ID | Guest_Name | Guest_Seat_No

```
   1   |    John     |      24
```

#### SEATS

#### Seat_No | Room_Location

```
  24   | 2nd Floor Room 11
```

---

**HERE IS MY SQL QUERY**

```
SELECT A.Guest_ID, A.Guest_Name, A.Guest_Seat_No, B.Room_Location
FROM GUESTS A JOIN SEATS B
ON A.Guest_Seat_No = B.Seat_No
WHERE A.Guest_ID = '1'
```

It seems there's something wrong in my query, its very difficult to determine the error because it just returns a **fatal error generated by codeIgniter** not the actual **sql syntax error** can someone please help me?

Comment: That error likely comes from the *adapter* (read: PDO driver) and not the DB engine itself: if it was a syntax error in the DB engine, then a suitable syntax error (from the engine) should be reported - I'm assuming that even FoxPro (rest its soul) does that. As such, include the relevant *PHP code* that results in the given error.

Comment: yes, but I dont want to mess with the internal code, I've encoutered this error many times before and it ends up I have an sql syntax error. it disappears when I've fixed the query, so it seems its in my query

Comment: What a shame :( Is there a way to access the DB by means of a Command Line Interface? That would allow quickly tearing apart and building up the query, and perhaps even getting a better error message. The posted code is valid *standard* SQL syntax, although what happens if it is simply a misspelled column name?

Comment: I've tried querying both tables individually and it was all fine. Will my query get the corresponding/respective **Room Location** even though my **WHERE** is on **Guest_ID** ?

Comment: The WHERE clause doesn't affect the shape of the query (the column names available) - it an only affect the number of records.

Comment: @user2246674 waa! cant believe it. you know what I was missing?? the word **INNER** it should be **INNER JOIN** . Usually **JOIN** works right? whew!.

Comment: INNER is optional (and implied) in *normal* SQL - anyway, glad you found the problem. I would really try to track down a CLI to troubleshoot such problems quicker in the future.

Comment: @user2246674 Yeah I thought so too, INNER was the default JOIN but It seems DBF-foxpro needed a quite more specific JOIN statement! haha, tnx for the help. more wisdom. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should define what kind of `JOIN` type you are using, like `INNER , LEFT, OUTER, FULL,`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.Guest_ID, A.Guest_Name, A.Guest_Seat_No, B.Room_Location
FROM GUESTS AS A
JOIN SEATS AS B ON A.Guest_Seat_No = B.Seat_No
WHERE A.Guest_ID = '1'
```

Comment: I think my code in assigning alias name to my table is ok but still tried your answer but same thing happend, error occured :(

Comment: You should always put information detailing what was wrong before, what needed to be changed and why, when answering such questions. Just posting code is considered a low quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whew, I cant believe I got stuck on this just because of the word **INNER** in **INNER JOIN** I usually use just JOIN because knowing INNER JOIN is the default right? maybe DBF foxpro really wants the keyword INNER in JOIN statement :) strict fellow. Anyway Thanks to all of you for the help.

```
SELECT A.Guest_ID, A.Guest_Name, A.Guest_Seat_No, B.Room_Location
FROM GUESTS A INNER JOIN SEATS B
ON A.Guest_Seat_No = B.Seat_No
WHERE A.Guest_ID = '1'
```

Comment: INNER is indeed the default for joins in Visual FoxPro, and you shouldn't have to explicitly supply it. It may be down to whatever driver PHP is using to talk to the database - I don't think you specified that.